# Change a project reference based on its configuration

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, teamcity

I have two solutions. One is a C# ASP.NET application `Foo`, the other is a class library `Bar`. In order for me to debug `Bar` in `Foo`, I need to add a reference to it which includes its symbols. All is well.

However, this reference breaks builds when uploading to TeamCity because it will look for a reference outside of the solution. So I need to make my project reference go from:

`../../bar/bin/bar.dll`

to

`../packages/bar.0.2.3/lib/bar.dll`

I am able to do this with MSBuild conditionals using the `Choose` tag.

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Bar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <HintPath>../../bar/bin/bar.dll</HintPath>
        <Private>True</Private>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Bar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <HintPath>../packages/bar.0.2.3/lib/bar.dll</HintPath>
        <Private>True</Private>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

This actually works beautifully. There is only one major problem: when I run an update command in Nuget, it will add a reference and overwrite my changes.

What is the easier way to do this? I'm open to any suggestions. Preferably, how can I modify a reference using a pre-build event? I just need to change one XML node based on a configuration.